# How do I pass the data from a renderDetailPanel in React/NextJS (i.e. `row`) to the function `handleSubmit`?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, textfield

how do I pass the data from `row` to `handleSubmit`

ie

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

// do something with row data but how do I even get it here??

setExampleData(row.original.ExampleData) //this does not work

}





renderDetailPanel={({ row }) => (

//blah blah code, no idea where to take row to put into the function 

<Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Action something to {row.original.info}</Button>

)
```

I tried to put it into one of the form slots inside renderDetailPanel, but the console came up as undefined. E.g.:

```
renderDetailPanel={({ row }) => (

//I put it here and hoped for the best but nothing came of it

<TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="message"
            value={message}
            label="Message"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMessage(e.target.value);
              setExampleData(row.original.ExampleData);  //over here
}}
/>

<Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Action something to {row.original.info}</Button>

)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, we will need a more complete code example. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows a working example that you ahve so far. I don't understand how the pieces you have given should work together enough to be able to answer your question.

Comment: You can pass row to handleSubmit by explicitly calling it inside an anonymous callback `onClick=(e)=>handleSubmit(e, row)`. Make sure to update the handleSubmit function to accept the row argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add `row` as a parameter to your `handleSubmit()` function:

```
const handleSubmit = (e, row) => {
    // do something with row here
}
```

Then use an anonymous function for the `onClick` handler to pass `row` to `handleSubmit()`:

```
<Button onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, row)}>...</Button>
```

Comment: OH MY GOOD NESS YOU ARE THE BEST

Comment: @supernewBs Please accept my answer when you are able if it solves your problem. You can also upvote it.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise. Have accepted it now